# Why "editor.matchBrackets": «always» not working for html on vsc 1.67.2?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Just traied a lot of stuff for fix this but it's just did'nt highlight my html brackets, but for js code it works properly.

Below img what i have now and what i want to get.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4uIx.png

Comment: The question about left and right pair angle brackets (<) (>) in html code that did not highlight in Virtual Studio Code, like what code did you ask ?? On screenshot you can see at left side how it works right now and on right side after red arrow how it must highlight properly.